# Error with dpkg debconf for every apt command

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debconf

I don't know what happened before, but now I've got this kind of error in Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook whenever I try to install any package/program though terminal or software center:

```
configuring tzdata
can't open /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
dpkg: error processing package tzdata(--configure):
post-installation returned error code 2
```

I checked this folder: `/usr/share/debconf` and found out that it contains nothing, that's why it cant be opened.
Used `dir` in terminal while in this folder, and it output nothing at all.

I tried reinstalling, deleting and checking this package, and even clearing cache of apt-get, but it didn't work nor fix the problem and raised the same error.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release?

Comment: And [edit] your question and add the output of `ll /usr/share/debconf/confmodule`

Comment: 14.03 LTS x64. Done.

Comment: Where is the output of `ll /usr/share/debconf/confmodule`?

Answer (score 0):

If the file `confmodule` is not in `/usr/share/debconf/`, than you have to reinstall the package `debconf` via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```

Comment: As i written above, i can't reinstall it and tried your command. It outputs the same error.